# Using Extract REGEX to leave only the Booking Reference from a URL String

Tags: regex, substring, extract, re2

I am attempting to extract data from the following string leaving me with only the booking reference, I have successfully done this with the Recipient ID reference but not the Booking reference.

```
URL /information/feedback?RECIPIENT_ID=fb8eab5f4738ad75e5093ee0f57ce1eb,fb8eab5f4738ad75e5093ee0f57ce1eb&BkRef=20927158&pid=email&sid=nfprog.
```

I have used the following to extract the Recipient ID which works
`REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page,'.RECIPIENT_ID=(.*),.*')` but not having any luck with the booking reference.

The BkRef will always be the same length i.e. 8 numerical characters `BkRef=20927158`

Comment: Regex is possibly not the best way to solve this problem. Many languages will have specific functions for parsing URL forms and parameters. I'd suggest adding the language and broader scope of what you're working in at least as tags to get broader visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[?&]BkRef=([^&]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TCljVO/2).

*Details*:

- `[?&]` - either `?` or `&`
- `BkRef=` - the name of the attribute
- `([^&]*)`  - Capturing group 1: zero or more chars other than `&`.

If there can be name references after the param, you can replace `([^&]*)` with `([^&#]*)`.

Comment: @Greg Do not say thank you, please read the guide. Thank you comments are off topic on this site.